# Dynamically changing gridview based on the value getting entered into a textbox

Tags: c#

I have a textbox and a gridview. The gridview is populated based on the value entered in the textbox. Suppose I am entering any name in the textbox. As I type the name in the textbox, the results in the grid should change dynamically. For example, if I am entering John in the textbox, after entering Jo, the grid should populate the results that start with Jo and if I enter h the grid should populate the results with Joh and so on. Please suggest me a solution (in c#) for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your grid's datasource?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the text changed event of your txtBox. And rebind the datagrid with the data that matches the textbox

```
private void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strValue = this.txtBox.Text;
    DataSet ds = ... // Get the dataset that matches strValue 
    this.dgrid.DataSource = ds;
}
```

However, this reloading the datagrid after each letter user types, would be a very costly operation. I would suggest providing a reload button after user is done with entering the text.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not very frequently changed (like many changes while user is on form or page) then you can get all the data and cache it in your for itself. Then you just filter this dataset based on the value entered into the textbox:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tb.Text == "")
        {
            //Unfilter the data
            gv.DataSource = dtb;
            return;
        }
        //Get default view of your data table and filter
        DataView dv = dtb.DefaultView;

        //Suppose your column name is "Value"
        dv.RowFilter = "Value like '" + tb.Text + "%'";

        gv.DataSource = dv;
    }
```

But don't you think filtering LARGE amount of data at every key press is heavy. You an do it at focus lost (blur) of text box or when user presses enter key. Just my thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great reference website on [Binding a DataGridView to Collection](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection).  This has the two way binding you are looking for.